# trouble assigning random numbers to 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I am really new to java and having a bit of trouble with this.  I have looked at other code on here and other places with similar problems but I do not understand the library files, etc. I'm trying to understand the basics now.  Any help would be appreciated.  My current code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[][] father = new double[25][25];
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            father[i] = Math.random();
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++){
                father[j] = Math.random();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the algorithms behind the coding, and this helps a lot!  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know java but a 2d array should work like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[][] father = new double[25][25];
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++){
                father[i][j] = Math.random();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set an array of doubles to a double. when trying to specify a certain item in the 2d array, always use arrayName[index1][index2].

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[][] father = new double[25][25];
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++){
            father[i][j] = Math.random();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A two-dimensional array, such as you have, requires both indexes in order to refer to a specific element. For example `father[3][6]` is an element of the array (a double, because that's the type of the array), but `father[i]` is not.

Also, you should use the array lengths, not hard-coded values, as the iteration limits. That way, if the array's size changes, you don't need to change the limits as well. Instead of `for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)` you should use `for (int i = 0; i < father.Length; i++)` so that if the length of the array changes you still iterate over the whole thing without overflowing.

All in all:

```
double[][] father = new double[25][25];
for (int i = 0; i < father.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < father[i].Length; j++) {
        father[i][j] = Math.random();
    }
}
```